# Dynamic population of usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a custom usercontrol and it is a dropdownbox with a button beside it.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlSelect" runat="server">        
        <asp:Label ID="lblNameSelect" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>:&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDivision" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
```

I need to create this during runtime.

```
        UserControl.UCDropDownBox drpDivision = LoadControl("~/UserControl/UCDropDownBox.ascx") as UserControl.UCDropDownBox;
        drpDivision.ID = "drp1";
        drpDivision.LabelText = "Division";
        drpDivision.DataSource = dt;
        drpDivision.DataTextField = "colDescription";
        drpDivision.DataValueField = "colValue";
        phFormContent.Controls.Add(drpDivision);
```

Now I want to generate the next usercontrol (same usercontrol) when the button from the first usercontrol is clicked so I can get the selectedvalue from the first usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be a LOT easier if you put your UserControl in a Repeater?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="multiControls" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlSelect" runat="server">        
        <asp:Label ID="lblNameSelect" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>:&nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDivision" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
  </asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

You could then bind a collection of objects to the Repeater.  Taking this approach, to solve your problem, all you need to do is:-

1. Add new item to collection
2. Re-bind Repeater

Not only does this vastly simplify the creation of new User Control objects, but it also makes loading previously persisted data a lot easier.

Comment: There are different usercontrols that I will be creating for this project. The next control will be displayed upon clicking the submit button of the previous usercontrol. Some controls will be dependent on the previous usercontrol's selected value. My problem actually is how to handle the submit button's onclick event so when its clicked, it will display the next usercontrol and pass the selectedvalue.